# How do I set up a proxy server that will SSH tunnel into a VPC I have in AWS for a Hibernate MySQL connection for me?

Tags: sql, hibernate, amazon-web-services, ssh, vpc

I have a microservice, let's call it RdsConnector, I want to test locally that is normally deployed on a machine on AWS. It connects to a MySQL instance, which is also in AWS, without any SSH tunnelling as they are in the same VPC. To connect to that MySQL instance from my local machine, I can use SSH tunnelling to get into the VPC I have set up in AWS. This is what that configuration looks like:

[image: ssh tunneling config]

I could set up my microservice to also connect through SSH (optionally, perhaps), but I don't want to do that. Then I would have a different configuration running it locally vs in the cloud. What I want to do instead is set up some kind of proxy server on my local machine that will take the SSH credentials and do that SSH tunnelling, exposing the VPC MySQL endpoint locally. Then RdsConnector will just use that local endpoint, and I won't have to have a different config for RdsConnector just for local testing.

I'm not very familiar with the networking technologies in use here. I just know that there's no public IPs for my VPC, so I have to SSH in. I imagine that what I want is possible, but I have no idea what the moving parts would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this turned out to be quite simple actually! The `ssh` program can do this for you, this is how I configure it with Mac OS `ssh`:

```
ssh -N -i "/Users/foo/aws_ssh_key.pem" \
    -L "localhost:5990:stack-name-vpc-db.asdfqwerty.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306" \
    foo@12.34.567.890
```

With the `-L` flag, it'll proxy stuff over the SSH connection for you from the given endpoint to the provided endpoint on the other side. That `-N` flag is optional, it just turns off the regular SSH console since we only want to run a proxy server. The microservice can treat `localhost:5990` as if it were the regular MySQL endpoint.